# Encountering Issues Importing Vue in Vue 3: Seeking Guidance on Troubleshooting and Resolution

Tags: vuejs3

I'm trying to migrate from Vue 2 to Vue 3, and I'm facing an issue when importing Vue in one of my components using the following code:

```
import Vue  from 'vue';
```

However, I'm encountering the following error.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no default import in `'vue'`.

For example `Vue.compile` is imported as `import {compile} from 'vue'`.

`Vue.use` became `import { createApp } from 'vue'; const app = createApp(...); app.use(....)` and so on.

Comment: So do I need to install all the plugins globally in the main.js where most of us `createApp`?

Comment: @Gevin yes, you could also check vue3 migration guide